# Convert scraped HTML table to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, python-requests

I would like to scrape a webpage containing data regarding all trains that have arrived and departed from Amsterdam Central station on a specific date, and convert it into a pandas dataframe.

I know I can scrape the webpage and convert it into a pandas dataframe like so (see below), but this doesn't give me the correct table.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/en/train-archive/2022-01-12/amsterdam-centraal'
response = requests.get(url).content

dfs = pd.read_html(response)
dfs[1]
```

What I like to achieve is one pandas dataframe containing all data that's under the header "Train services" of the webpage, like so:

```
Arrival    Departure  Destination          Type        Train   Platform   Composition
02:44 +2½  02:46 +2   Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity   1409    4a         VIRM-4 9416
03:17 +5   03:19 +4   Utrecht Centraal     Intercity   1410    7a         ICM-3 4086
03:44      03:46      Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity   1413    7a         ICM-3 4014
04:17      04:19      Utrecht Centraal     Intercity   1414    7a         ICM-4 4216
04:44      04:46      Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity   1417    7a         ICM-3 4086
...        ...        ...                  ...         ...     ...        ...
```

I hope there's someone able to help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_html` needs a `<table>` to populate the dtaframe, it doesn't exists in the html. I suggest you use `BeautifulSoup` instead

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/en/train-archive/2022-01-12/amsterdam-centraal'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

columns = soup.find('div', class_='row header')
columns = columns.text.strip().split('\n\n')

tables = soup.find_all('div', class_='row service')
data = []
for table in tables:
    row = table.find_all('div', recursive=False)
    data.append([cell.text.replace('\n', '') for cell in row[:-1]] + [', '.join(t['title'] for t in row[-1].find_all('span'))])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

Output

```
       Arrival  Departure          Destination        Type   Train  Platform   Composition
0    02:44 +2½   02:46 +2   Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity    1409        4a   VIRM-4 9416
1     03:17 +5   03:19 +4     Utrecht Centraal   Intercity    1410        7a    ICM-3 4086
2        03:44      03:46   Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity    1413        7a    ICM-3 4014
3        04:17      04:19     Utrecht Centraal   Intercity    1414        7a    ICM-4 4216
4        04:44      04:46   Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity    1417        7a    ICM-3 4086
..          ...        ...                  ...         ...     ...       ...          ...
784      01:04      01:14              Alkmaar    Sprinter    7384       10a    SLT-4 2465
785           —     01:19     Utrecht Centraal   Intercity    1402        7a   VIRM-6 8648
786      01:44   01:46 +1   Rotterdam Centraal   Intercity   11405       13a    ICM-4 4239
787      02:17      02:19     Utrecht Centraal   Intercity    1406       11a    ICM-4 4247
788      03:17   03:19 +1     Utrecht Centraal   Intercity   11410       11a    ICM-3 4076
```

Comment: Some trains consists of two train units. For example, the train's composition below consists of a `SLT-4 2435` and a `SLT-6 2631` unit. The current script only selects the first unit. How do I make sure that both units are selected and added to the `composition` column like so: `SLT-4 2435, SLT-6 2631` ?

<div class="material">
<div class="material-parts">
<span class="material-part" title="SLT-4 2435">
<img src="/images/train-material/mat_slt4.png"/> </span>
<span class="material-part" title="SLT-6 2631">
<img src="/images/train-material/mat_slt6.png"/> </span>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @sampeterson edited the code, I replaced the `data.append(...)` line in the `for` loop.